# NUnit console - when attempting to redirect output /err seems to have no effect

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I've got an Nunit project with some tests and they all run as expected. Now I want to incorporate the running of these scripts automatically.
I'm trying to use some of the redirect options so I can separate the test output, but whatever combination I use, all I seem to get is the standard TestResult.xml. I can use /out:AnnotherOut.txt OK, but I'm really interested in capturing the error output using /err:TestErrors.txt.
Command line is:
(NunitConsole App) /nologo /framework:net-4.0 MyTestProject.nunit /include=Integration /err=TestErrors.txt

Comment: I should add that TestErrors.txt is created as an empty file, and the console output is the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949477/how-can-i-suppress-nunit-console-output